# Split phrase into sentences that start with a specific word

Tags: regex, perl

I want to split a phrase into more sentences having as delimiter a given word. Example of input phrase:

```
You must go right now.
She was walking quickly to the mall.
He should wait before going swimming.
Those girls are not trying very hard.
Ted might eat the cake.
You must go right now.
You can’t eat that!
My mother is fixing us some dinner.
Words were spoken.
These cards may be worth hundreds of dollars!
The teacher is writing a report.
You have woken up everyone in the neighborhood.
```

What I am expecting to get would be : 
1)

```
You must go right now.
She was walking quickly to the mall.
He should wait before going swimming.
Those girls are not trying very hard.
Ted might eat the cake.
```

2)

```
 You must go right now.
```

3)

```
You can’t eat that!
```

And so on...

Using this code I managed to get all of them, except the last one (because there is no `You` at the final of the phrase to be matched):

```
my $string = 'the phrase above';
my @results = ($string =~ /.+?(?=You)/g);
```

Also I noticed if the string has `\n` separators, the regex will stop at the first line.

Comment: @AvinashRaj That won't catch anything :(

Comment: Oh, then do a split using `/[\r\n](?=You)/` regex..

Comment: @AvinashRaj That will catch all the phrase.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/2fdzEa/1

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yeah, you're right, it works, thanks a lot! You can also post is as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: `/[\r\n]You)/\n\nYou/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a simple split instead of matching.

```
my @text = split /[\r\n](?=You)/, $text;
```

This would do splitting on newline or carriage return character which was exists just before to the string `You`.

In-order to do a clean split , it's better to add `+`, ie. `[\r\n]+`

Comment: I did not put a `[\r\n]+`, instead I used an optional one `[\r\n]?` because the phrase may or may not be multi-line.

Comment: then it should be `(?<=[.!?])\s*(?=You)`